# recommended place to store nexus data

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I have installed [nexus 3](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/category/nexus-3/) on my server at `/mydir/nex/local/lib/nexus`. This lays down the normal structure. 
So I have my data directory pointed to the default `-Dkaraf.data=../sonatype-work/nexus3`. I have a mounted file system on `/mydir/nex` where the data installation lives.

Since the installation is under `/mydir/nex`, should I create a `/mydir/nex/data`? 
Or is it okay to leave the data on the default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always fond of using FHS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), which means standard folders. So Nexus is put in /opt/nexus and data will go to /var/(opt)/nexus. Logging goes to /var/log/nexus.

It is ok to leave the data under the application if you like and it is also okey of you put it in another directory, it will not break Nexus in any case.